# Network crashes and doesn't restart Debian

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ethernet

I'm running Debian Jessie and every few days my network will stop working under heavy load, not allowing any connections in or out. I don't know why it stops working and why it won't come back online. If I run

```
systemctl status networking
```

it says the network is running. My /etc/network/interfaces is

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I'm running Jessie because my ethernet card wasn't supported in wheezy. If I run lspci my ethernet card is

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
```

Perhaps the issue is due to the ethernet controller? I know people have had problems getting similar cards to work under wheezy, but support has been added in jessie. Yes, I know Jessie is in testing and 100% reliability should not be expected, I'm just asking if there is something I am doing incorrectly.

Additionally, if I restart networking using

```
systemctl restart networking
```

there is still no connection. It would be very nice if at the least I could manually restart the network.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the terminal:

```
ifdown eth0 
ifup eth0
```

And if this does not work then:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Perform this commands as superuser.

Comment: I'm not sure how ifdown/ifup will work when this happens again.  They show that it is working currently because it actually is.  The /etc/init.d/networking restart does not work however.  I  have tried this previously and it does not restore connectivity.